# Constructing an increasing sequence of numbers from a set

Tags: proof-verification

I have an infinite set $A$ of real numbers and I wish to construct a strictly increasing sequence using elements of $A$. This is what came to my mind -

Pick any element from $A$ and name it $a_1$. Pick a different element from $A$. If this is greater than $a_1$, call it $a_2$. If not, rename the first element $a_2$ and the new one $a_1$. Suppose I have chosen $a_1<a_2<…<a_n$. Pick an element $a$ different from all these. If $a>a_n$, name it $a_{n+1}$. If $a<a_1$, rename $a_i$ as $a_{i+1}$ for all $i$, and $a$ as $a_1$. If $a_k<a<a_{k+1}$, rename $a$ to $a_{k+1}$ and $a_i$ to $a_{i+1}$ for $i\geq k+1$. This way I have $a_1<a_2<…<a_n<a_{n+1}$. Then by induction I have my increasing sequence $(a_n)$.

Am I allowed to do this? Did I invoke any axiom while doing this?

Comment: What if your set is not countable?  You couldn't do this with the real numbers for instance.  Or the set of all irrational numbers.

Comment: @fleablood: I disagree. We can do this with both the reals and the irrationals. Consider the sequence $a_n=\pi+n.$

Comment: TonyK's answer is the one you want. Mine only gets you partway there with "not necessarily," but his shows that you simply can't do it.

Comment: @fleablood: the question doesn't say that the sequence has to contain _all_ the elements of $A$.

Comment: @TonyK you're right I thought it did say that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This proves you can create an increasing sequence of any finite length (because if a sequence of length $n$ can be made, then a sequence of length $n+1$ can be made) but not an increasing sequence of infinite length (because for any $n$ you can "go one more" to length $n+1$ but adding one will never get you to length $\infty$) .

It's a subtle but important point that induction can give you a conclusion for all natural values but *not* for a countable infinite value.[1]

In this case it will be possible that for an infinite number of attempts we will find a number $<$ than $a_1$ and thus a new $a_1$ will be assigned an infinite number of times and there will be no "final" $a_1$ for the infinite sequence.

As Tony Ks answer shows  the set is $\{-1,-2, -3, ....\}$ then the first sequence will be $\{a_1\} = \{-1\}$ and the second sequence will be $\{a_1, a_2\} = -2, -1$, and so on.  Then $n$ sequence will be $\{a_1, ....  a_n\} = \{-n, -n+1, ...., -1\}$.  But each sequence will always have a *different* $a_1$ and there will be no "agreed upon" $a_1$ for an infinite sequence.

[1]  A false proof that all real numbers between $0$ and $1$ is rational:  If every decimal with $n$ places is rational then a decimal with $n+1$ spaces $0.a_1a_2....a_na_{n+1} = 0.a_1a_2.....a_n + \frac {a_{n+1}}{10^{n+1}}$ is the sum of two rational numbers and hence rational.  So by induction every decimal with any number of places is rational.  As every real number between $0$ and $1$ can be written a decimal with some number (possibly infinite) places, every such real number is rational.

The catch is that induction only proves something about decimals with *finite* number of places.  Not infinite number of places.  Although we can "add $1$" an infinite number of times to get an infinite number of numbers, those numbers are all *finite*.  We can never "add $1$" and ever get $\infty$.

Comment: Is the axiom of choice at all used while constructing a sequence from a set?

Answer (score 2):

You are not allowed to do this. As a counter-example, suppose your set $A$ consists of the negative integers: $A=\{-1,-2,-3,\ldots\}$. Then there exists no strictly increasing  infinite sequence of elements of $A$!

Comment: Very nice example. Which line in my "proof" was incorrect then?

Comment: "This way I have a1<a2<…<an<an+1. Then by induction I have my increasing sequence"  Your mistake is by induction you can have a sequence of any *finite* length.  That doesn't mean you can have a sequence of *infinite* length.

Comment: @fleablood That is the answer I was hoping to get. Because this is something that has confused me for a long time. In our class we have always constructed sequence "by induction". Like "after choosing $a_n$ do this and get $a_{n+1}$. Thus we have our sequence by induction." But induction only says when a subset of naturals is the whole set.

Comment: Okay, ... in those cases you are adding numbers, one at a time, adding each *to the end of a sequence* with each number having the property.  In this case each step you are make a new *sequence* (not a new *number*) by adding a number in *different* places.  So what you get is a sequence of *sequences*.  Each sequence is increasing and finite and there are an infinite number of sequences but there is no final sequence in the end.

Comment: Your first sequence is $a_1 = \{a_{1,1}\}$ a sequence of one term.  You second sequence is $a_2 = \{a_{2,1},a_{2,2}\}$ a sequence of two terms.  Your $k$th sequence is $a_k=\{a_{k,1},a_{k,2},....,a_{k,}\}$  a sequence of $k$ terms.  Your final result is $\{a_1,a_2, a_3....\}$ an infinite sequence *of sequences* where each sequence is a *finite* increasing sequence.  But you haven't found a way to convert this sequence of sequences into a single infinite sequence *of numbers*.